# Doctrine naming strategy is not mapping default values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony doctrine-bundle, orm extension. Problem is in auto mapping. It maps values which are defined in doctrine-mapping fine but doesn't map results which are not defined in this file. Symfony: 4.3, doctrine-orm: 2.6, mysql

I have tried using different naming strategies: underscore, default.

entity example class:

```
<?php 
class example {
    private $email;
    private $lastName;
    private $firstName;
}
?>
```

orm.xml:

```
    <entity name="example" table="users">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

        <field name="lastName" column="last_name"/>
        <field name="firstName" column="first_name"/>

    </entity>
```

yaml:

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

And in the example entity, I get lastName & firstName properties set but not email.

Comment: I don't see a definition for `email` in `orm.xml`—is it missing?

Comment: yes its not in orm.xml because what i learned from documentation: Using a naming strategy you can provide rules for generating database identifiers, column or table names when the column or table name is not given. This feature helps reduce the verbosity of the mapping document, eliminating repetitive noise

Comment: You still have to provide the mapping. You can have properties in your entities that are not persisted to database. [`auto_mapping`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle) just loads your definitions automatically, doesn't generate them. And `naming_strategy` controls how to generate column names from *mapped* property names, nothing more.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I have never used Doctrine 2's XML mapping, only annotations. I would have assumed that, similar to annotations, you need to explicitly declare your mappable properties. There's not a lot of magic in Doctrine compared to other ORMs in my experience, and there are use cases where you would have properties that are not to be mapped... Which would be contrary to the idea of implicit mapping. Can you point to some documentation about this?

Comment: Documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/namingstrategy.html

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/xml-mapping.html#xml-mapping

Comment: So is there a way to skip entity mapping if the entity property name is equal to the database column name? Or doctrine doesn't provide such functionality?

Comment: No, I think you need to be explicit—that's no bad thing. Doctrine would not know the difference between a property you want mapped and one you don't want mapped otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `naming_strategy` controls how to generate column names from mapped property names, but it doesn't automatically generate the mapping itself by comparing the Entity with its corresponding table. [`auto_mapping`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle) just loads your definitions automatically.

Since you can have properties in your entities that are not persisted to the database or viceversa you have to define all mappings. Doing this allows doctrine to keep track of your database schema and update your database with new properties/columns via Migrations.

If you are feeling lazy and have an existing database, you can also generate (or update) your Entities from it. In this case, all columns will be mapped to the Entity and you can then remove those fields that aren't of use to you.

If what you want is to reduce the verbosity of your mapping file what you can do is drop the `column` property. Doctrine will then auto-generate the column name according to the `naming_strategy` specified. You only have to explicitly set it when it's different from what Doctrine will generate. For instance, since you are using `underscore` strategy you can just say:

```
<field name="lastName"/>
<field name="firstName"/>
<field name="email"/>
```

This will result in the exact same mapping you are using. Then if you need a field with different name, you *override* it by specifying `column`.

```
<field name="address" column="home_address"/>
```